# Is it normal for a company to ask for a photo ID when finishing my new-hire paperwork?

Tags: new-job, united-states, new-hires, security

I've been hired by a company recently and now they're finishing my paperwork. Today, I was asked to provide a photo ID. I'm going to use a picture of my license. I want to make sure this is normal procedure. I believe driver's license is public record so more than likely I won't be risking anything. I just like to be sure.

I'm from the United States.

Comment: Did you meet them on the internet?

Comment: I expect you mean 'new-hire paperwork', not immigration paperwork, tax paperwork, job application etc. Please edit the title as needed.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of negativity being expressed toward the OP in comments. IMO this question is perfectly reasonable. People should understand the privacy implications of things that they are being forced to do, and it's reasonable to ask about those privacy implications. Personally, I find it creepy and weird to be living in a time and place where a person needs government-issued photo ID in order to live. Historically, this is a recent innovation. There is also a slippery slope here that leads to internal passports as in the USSR.

Comment: Where I work, we have to submit 2 forms of ID. I use drivers license and US Passport. I suppose birth certificate would do as well.

Comment: Showing your company your ID is very normal in the United States. _Giving_ your employer your ID to hold on to long-term is an enormous red flag, so that's what you should be weary of. But it is something that I have never heard a reputable company in the USA trying to do, so I would be astonished if someone asked you to do that.

Comment: @ringo A driver's license is not enough, because it doesn't show your nationality. They don't want to risk illegally employing someone

Comment: @BenCrowell Thank mechanized travel: the automobile and the jetliner. As for internal passports, that happened before we were born, thanks again to mechanised travel, you can't just let anyone drive a car after all.  Maybe once automatic cars become fully trusted and you do not need a drivers license to be chaffeured in one, only people with Red Barchettas (manual cars) will need driver licenses, and when we can go back to most people not routinely carrying around ID.

Comment: I applaud you for being sceptical of providing people with identification documents. It being standard practice does not necessarily make it a good practice. Also, note that your employer may be required to *verify* your identity, but to do strictly that, they will need to have *a look at* your ID and at you. Merely having a photocopy of identification documents is not proof of your identity or authenticity, and may not be required legally either. The fewer copies are made of your sensitive documents, the fewer possibilities arise for identity theft and other fraud.

Comment: You need a photo ID for a rec membership or even to rent a tuxedo. Requiring one for employment is not out of the norm. If you have concerns about the employer and their handling of such data, you should follow up with them, but also note that it might counterproductively raise suspicion of you.

Comment: @BenCrowell While I echo your privacy concerns, a 'slippery slope' argument is a logical fallacy. There's no reason to believe that employers requiring photo ID is going to lead to a restriction of free movement throughout the US.

Comment: I think the red flag is that they've asked him to send a photo of his ID: *I'm going to use a picture of my license.*. While I've had to show ID for jobs, I've always provided it in person -- I'm surprised this employer will even accept a photo of the drivers license.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In the United States, employers are required to complete an I-9 form that verifies you have the legal authority to work. That form **requires** the employer to check your ID, and includes a list of acceptable IDs. ([USCIS page on I-9](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9))

> #LISTS OF ACCEPTABLE DOCUMENTS
> All documents must be UNEXPIRED.
>
> Employees may present one selection from List A or a combination of
> one selection from List B and one selection from List C.
>
> ##LIST A
>
> ###Documents that Establish Both Identity and Employment Authorization
>
> 1. U.S. Passport or U.S. Passport Card
> 2. Permanent Resident Card or Alien Registration Receipt Card (Form I-551)
> 3. Foreign passport that contains a temporary I-551 stamp or temporary I-551 printed notation on a machinereadable immigrant visa
> 4. Employment Authorization Document that contains a photograph (Form I-766)
> 5. For a nonimmigrant alien authorized to work for a specific employer because of his or her status:
> 6. Foreign passport; and
> 7. Form I-94 or Form I-94A that has the following:
> 8. The same name as the passport; and
> 9. An endorsement of the alien's nonimmigrant status as long as that period of endorsement has not yet expired and the proposed
>    employment is not in conflict with any restrictions or limitations
>    identified on the form
> 10. Passport from the Federated States of Micronesia (FSM) or the Republic of the Marshall Islands (RMI) with Form I-94 or Form I-94A
>     indicating nonimmigrant admission under the Compact of Free
>     Association Between the United States and the FSM or RMI
>
> ##LIST B
> ###Documents that Establish Identity
>
> 1. Driver's license or ID card issued by a State or outlying possession of the United States provided it contains a photograph or
>    information such as name, date of birth, gender, height, eye color,
>    and address
> 2. ID card issued by federal, state or local government agencies or entities, provided it contains a photograph or information such as
>    name, date of birth, gender, height, eye color, and address
> 3. School ID card with a photograph
> 4. Voter's registration card
> 5. U.S. Military card or draft record
> 6. Military dependent's ID card
> 7. U.S. Coast Guard Merchant Mariner Card
> 8. Native American tribal document
> 9. Driver's license issued by a Canadian government authority
>
> **For persons under age 18 who are unable to present a document listed above:**
>
> 10. School record or report card
> 11. Clinic, doctor, or hospital record
> 12. Day-care or nursery school record
>
> ##LIST C
> ###Documents that Establish Employment Authorization
>
> 1. A Social Security Account Number card, unless the card includes one of the following restrictions:
> 2. NOT VALID FOR EMPLOYMENT
> 3. VALID FOR WORK ONLY WITH INS AUTHORIZATION
> 4. VALID FOR WORK ONLY WITH DHS AUTHORIZATION
> 5. Certification of report of birth issued by the Department of State (Forms DS-1350, FS-545, FS-240)
> 6. Original or certified copy of birth  certificate issued by a State,  county, municipal authority, or  territory of the United States
>    bearing an official seal
> 7. Native American tribal document
> 8. U.S. Citizen ID Card (Form I-197)
> 9. Identification Card for Use of Resident Citizen in the United States (Form I-179)
> 10. Employment authorization document issued by the Department of Homeland Security

[image: transcription above]

Comment: Could you include the list of acceptable IDs in your answer because when I tried to check in the link I got the nice message "Please wait...your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document"?

Comment: @zakinster you'll get that error if you try to open the document in a browser, you need to download it and then open it in a valid PDF viewer such as adobe acrobat.

Comment: @williamporter No, even downloading & opening it will result in that message (I just did it) unless you have one of a small subset of viewers (e.g. Adobe Acrobat). Other viewers are completely "valid" - this is a fairly unnecessary restriction. Also we prefer to have the content here rather than requiring people to download external resources to get the answer (though of course the external site should be considered authoritative!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which is why I edited the post to include an image of the valid documents (should be in review queue currently). I figured I'd explain the source of the error to them however, as that seems polite. Also note that providing the content here could be an issue, as there may be updates to the list by the relevant authority, which a person simply viewing this question may not see.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: PDF Xchange opened it (the printable I-9 form, and the instructions, and the fillable I-9 form) just fine, so it is not restricted to Adobe.

Comment: From what I can tell, that list does not require that your ID be photo ID, in fact, the drivers license section says that it should contain a photograph or personally identifying information. Obviously photo ID is easier and more common these days.

Answer (score 33):

100% standard.  They're just verifying that the person in front of them is the person they are claiming to be.

Comment: Reasons being that they clarify you're the person claiming to be able to do the job and you're not dodging tax.

Comment: And in the USA, a US passport also proves that you have the right to work. A German passport for example would show that you are who you claim to be, but you would have to show separately that you have the right to work in the USA.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is very much normal in most of the organizations around the world. For example: Passport / voter ID card is the most common ones used in my country.

Answer (score 0):

In most countries, the employer must check that you have the right to work. This has two obvious parts: They have to check that you are who you say you are, and that you have the right to work. Most people are lucky and their identity gives them the right to work. In the USA, that would be any official photo ID that also shows you are a US citizen, typically in the USA a US passport or US driving license, or a document showing that you have the right of work that also has a photo.

In the UK it used to be that any EU passport identified you and gave you the right of work. Nowadays only a UK passport gives you the right of work; an EU passport identifies you and then there is a simple procedure to check that you have the right of work. US citizens would have to show their passport and an additional document showing their right to work.

Comment: A US driver's license does not show that you are a US citizen or that you have the right to work. Some states issue driver's licenses to non-citizen residents, and some states issue them to undocumented residents.